# Intersection of augmented types infered as intersection of original types

Tags: typescript, module-augmentation

I'm trying to augment an interface from an external dependency.
The reason is that the external `d.ts` file does not specify the full return types.
In the example below, `doStuff()` actually exists on objects returned by `Bar.giveList()` and `Baz.giveList()`, but the original declaration does not contain this information.
The following is a reconstruction of the problem using `declare global` (I'm actually trying to augment named modules, but the problem seems to be similar when using two `declare global` blocks in a single file).

```js
export type MyList<T> = T[] & {
    doStuff(): void
}

declare global { // Original declaration from external dependency
    export interface Bar {
        giveList(): string[]
    }
    export interface Baz {
        giveList(): string[]
    }
}

declare global { // My attempt of refining some return types
    export interface Bar {
        giveList(): MyList<string>
    }
    export interface Baz {
        giveList(): MyList<string>
    }
}

let bar        = {} as Bar
let baz        = {} as Baz
let barbaz     = {} as (Bar | Baz)

let barList    = bar.giveList()     // infered type: MyList<string> --- good
let bazList    = baz.giveList()     // infered type: MyList<string> --- good
let barbazList = barbaz.giveList()  // infered type: string[]       --- why not MyList<string>?

barList.doStuff()                   // good
barList[0]                          // good
bazList.doStuff()                   // good
bazList[0]                          // good
barbazList.doStuff()                // ERROR: Property 'doStuff' does not exist on type 'string[]'.(2339)
barbazList[0]                       // good
```

Since `Bar.giveList()`and `Baz.giveList()` return `MyList<string>`, why doesn't `(Bar|Baz).giveList()` return `MyList<string>` as well?

Edit: I simplified the problem and created a ticket: [ms/TS#57319](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57319)

Comment: It's a known design limitation of TypeScript, see [ms/TS#50488](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50488). The compiler takes the shortcut of picking a single call signature (usually the lowest priority one, assumed to be the most general) when analyzing overload types, which isn't always what people want. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I don't understand the Typescript compiler very well, so I struggle to see how this is the same problem, since it does not involve declaration merging/augmentation. I would be thankful for an explanation.

Comment: Merging in a method that already exists is equivalent to adding an overload as a higher priority.  So `interface Foo { m(): X }` followed by merging in `interface Foo { m(): Y }` is equivalent to the single declaration `interface Foo {m():Y; m():X}`.  Does that explain the connection? I'm happy to write this up as an answer but I want to make sure we're on the same page before I do so, so as not to waste either of our time by writing up an answer that doesn't actually address the question fully.

Comment: @jcalz I think I'm starting to understand. But why are `Bar` and `Baz` as expected, but not `(Bar | Baz)`

Comment: Because it's just calling the overload directly, which is the only time when TS analyzes the overload list "properly".  (If it *never* did that, then overloads would be *completely* useless, as opposed to just *often* useless).  I'm writing up an answer now.

Comment: Ok, it's starting to make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known design limitation of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#50488](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50488) for an authoritative answer.

---

From the [documentation for declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html):

> For function members, each function member of the same name is treated as describing an overload of the same function. Of note, too, is that in the case of interface `A` merging with later interface `A`, the second interface will have a higher precedence than the first.

So `Bar` and `Baz` end up being equivalent to this:

```
interface Bar {
  giveList(): MyList<string>
  giveList(): string[]
}
interface Baz {
  giveList(): MyList<string>
  giveList(): string[]
}
```

where `giveList()` is an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) method.

---

And, unfortunately, overloads are fragile in TypeScript.

A direct call to a declared overloaded method will resolve to the most appropriate call signature.  That's what happens in `bar.giveList()` and `baz.giveList()`; in each case, the compiler walks through the list of call signatures and selects the most appropriate one... which is the higher priority `giveList()`, the one that returns `MyList<string>`.

But any other manipulation or analysis of overloaded methods causes TypeScript to take a shortcut. It essentially chooses one call signature without figuring out which one is the most appropriate.  Usually this is the one with the *least* priority, assuming that it's the most general (this assumption is incorrect in your example, which is why things go wrong).  So when determining the type of `giveList()` of the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `Bar | Baz`, the compiler just chooses the lowest priority signature, the one that returns `string[]`.  And then you have a union of things that return `string[]`, and you get `string[]`.

---

So that's what's going on.  Really you don't actually want to *merge* in the `giveList()` method, but actually *modify* the existing `Bar` and `Baz` interfaces to return `MyList<string>` and not `string[]`.  But TypeScript has no facility to modify existing interfaces, apart from you manually forking the library and modifying the types locally.

There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#19064](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19064) asking to allow people to *remove* overloads and then presumably overwrite them with other ones.  This is really what you're trying to do.  But it's not supported by TypeScript and given the lack of overwhelming community support for it (it has only a handful of upvotes) I wouldn't expect to see it implemented anytime soon (even very highly requested features do not usually get implemented quickly).

Comment: Great explanation, thank you.
Interestingly, if I change `T[]` to `Array<T>` in the library code, and define an `interface Array<T>` (declaring `doStuff()`) in my `declare` block, I can achieve my goal.
Alas, the library used `T[]`, which does not seem to be equivalent to `Array<T>` to the compiler in this case.
Do you have any idea if it is possible to get around this limitation?

Comment: That seems like a followup question and I'm not prepared to delve into it.  Are you sure you're merging into the global `Array`?  I'm surprised that there would be a difference there.  But again, I'm not really prepared to explore that here.

Comment: Something like this (unexpectedly) works:
```
declare global { 
    export interface Bar {
        giveList(): Array<string>
    }
    export interface Baz {
        giveList(): Array<string>
    }
}

declare global { 
    export interface Array<T>{
        doStuff(): void
    }
}
```
Anyway, as you say, it's a seperate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change interface you will need to extends it

```
declare global {
    export interface NewBar extends Bar {
        giveList(): MyList<string>
    }
    export interface NewBaz extends Baz {
        giveList(): MyList<string>
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to modify the existing interfaces, not create new interfaces.
The interfaces (Bar, Baz) are used all around, having interfaces with a different name would not help me.
I'm trying to do [module/global augmentation](https://typescript-v2-784.vercel.app/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation), not inheritance.